# How do I get the MySQL error report during script run?

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a data migration from one table to another table.
So I have two tables T1 & T2.
T1- source table
T2- destination table.
While running the insert query from T1 to T2 there might be a possibility that some of the records may not insert into the T2 table due to some errors.
So I want to capture those errors and put them in one file or any other table also fine.

Comment: If an error occures than the copying will be aborted and none row will be copied. The error message should be received using according function of your data access library or queried with `SHOW WARNING;` query immediately after `INSERT`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm doing insert ingonre, so even if error comes it will proceed with next record to execute .

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` treates errors as warnings. You may retrieve all problematic points via `SHOW WARNINGS;` immediately after your INSERT (none intermediate statements - compulsory) executed in the same connection (critical). But sometimes the problematic row identifying is not possible. [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ada1ef6e541ce389e94f36ad048d04f5)

Comment: From the demo link I can see warnings we can display, can I capture these warnings and add to another table or CSV file to treat it as error report.